# How to iterate date in for loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have some values.

```
 DateTime date=04/03/2015(date)
 Total Woring days=6 (total)
 Rotation Days=2 (rotationday)
 Shift Group=S1(this group contain two shift id 1 and 2)
```

I want to run the shift for 6 days. but after each 2 days Shift id 1 rotate to shift id 2 and again after two days shift id 2 rotate to shift id 1 and so on...
My output should be like

```
04/03/2015=1
05/03/2015=1
06/03/2015=2
07/03/2015=2
08/03/2015=1
09/03/2015=1
```

I am getting shift id through a foreach loop. I tried like below mentioned way but not getting a proper resul. Please help me solve this issue

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select ShiftID from ShiftGroup  where  
ShiftName='" + ide + "'", conn2);
SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
DataSet ds4 = new DataSet();
var rows2 = ds4.Tables[0].Rows;
if (ds4.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
foreach (DataRow row2 in rows2)
{
string shiftname = Convert.ToString(row2["ShiftID"]);
DateTime date=04/03/2015(date)
Total Woring days=6 (total)
Rotation Days=2 (rotationday)
DateTime rotation= date.AddDays(rotationday);//
DateTime totaldate = date.AddDays(workingdays);
for (DateTime rotation = date; rotation <= totaldate; rotation = rotation.AddDays(1))//total working days 
{
    //to check rotation date
if (rotation <= totaldate )
{
allocation.shiftallocation( rotation, shiftid);
}
}
}
```

I am stucked with this from last day, anybody help me . No need of consider my for loop, kindly provide a for loop which generate the above mentioned output

Comment: What is `rt` ? What's it's value ?

Comment: @Coder of Code, Kindly check my updated question please

Comment: Should you consider holidays?

Comment: @Sarathy, I didnt get what you mean actually

Comment: Are you considering 7 days in a week as working days or only 5 days a week with Saturday and Sunday as Holidays?

Comment: @Sarathy,5 days working day with rotation shift and after that off day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,

```
     DateTime date=DateTime.ParseExact("04/03/2015","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime totaldate = date.AddDays(6);
    for (int i=0; date <= totaldate; date = date.AddDays(1),i++)//total working days 
     {

         if((i/2)%2==0)
              Console.WriteLine(date+" "+1);
         else
              Console.WriteLine(date+" "+2);
     }
```

Comment: dates comes as my output but shiftid not rotating its only 1 not rotate to 2

Comment: But that goes 1,2,1,2, etc. OP wants 1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2, etc.

Comment: @JimMischel I marked it to delete because I misunderstood the question. But it's still not deleted.

Comment: Now, if you changed that to `if ((i/2)%2 == 0)` . . .

Comment: @Coder of Code, It work but I have another question to you. Can u come in chat

Comment: Yes you can come in chat

Comment: Got to [this link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=recent) and search for `Coder Of Code` and send request to chat.

Comment: @Coder of Code, I couldnt find you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72207/discussion-between-mohan-lal-and-coder-of-code).

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("04/03/2015");

var totalWorkingDays = 6;
var rotationDays = 2;

var rotationId = 1;
var rotationCounter = 1;

for (DateTime rotation = date; 
     rotation <= date.AddDays(totalWorkingDays); 
     rotation = rotation.AddDays(1))
{
    Console.WriteLine(rotation + " " + rotationId);

    if (rotationCounter++ == 2)
    {
        rotationCounter = 1;
        rotationId = 3 - rotationId;
    }
}
```

Or, with a linq query

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("04/03/2015");

var totalWorkingDays = 6;
var rotationDays = 2;

foreach (var d in Enumerable.Range(0, totalWorkingDays)
               .Select((i, index) => date.AddDays(i) + 
                   (((int)(index / rotationDays)) % 2 == 1 ? " 2" : " 1")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use dates at loop cycle, use abstract indicies. You can really abstract from concrete numbers and use only variables for managing result. So you can easily change rotationDays count and even workshifts labels array without changing cycle.

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("04/03/2015");

        var totalWorkingDays = 15;
        var rotationDays = 2;

        var workshifts = new[] { "S1", "S2" };
        var currentWorkshiftIndex = 0;
        for (int dayIndex = 0; dayIndex <= totalWorkingDays; dayIndex++) {
            if (dayIndex != 0 && dayIndex % rotationDays == 0) currentWorkshiftIndex = (currentWorkshiftIndex + 1) % workshifts.Length;
            Console.WriteLine(date.AddDays(dayIndex) + " " + workshifts[currentWorkshiftIndex]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution with holidays taken into account.

```
int totalDays = 10;
int rotationDays = 3;
int[] shifts = new[] { 1, 2 };
string startDate = "04/03/2015";
var holidays = new List<DayOfWeek>(new[] { DayOfWeek.Saturday, DayOfWeek.Sunday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday });
var shiftAllocations = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();
int currentShiftIndex = 0;

DateTime current = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

for (int i = 0; i < totalDays; i += rotationDays)
{
    var currentShiftId = shifts[currentShiftIndex];

    // For each day from the current day till the number of shift rotation days, allocate the shift.
    for (int j = 0; j < rotationDays;)
    {
        // If the current day is a holiday, move to the next day by incrementing i.
        if (holidays.Contains(current.AddDays(i + j).DayOfWeek))
        {
            i++;                        
            continue;
        }

        shiftAllocations.Add(current.AddDays(i + j), currentShiftId);
        j++;
    }

    // Increase the shift index if the value is within the bounds. If not reset the index to the beginning
    if ((currentShiftIndex + 1) >= shifts.Length)
        currentShiftIndex = 0;
    else
        currentShiftIndex++;
}

foreach (var kvp in shiftAllocations)
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ":" + kvp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment for the 5 working days a week, I wrote this:

```
  var start = new DateTime(2015, 04, 03);
  var working_day_count = 6;
  var rotation_interval = 2;
  var shifts = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

  var rotation_count = 1;
  var shift_index = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < working_day_count; i++) {
    while ((start.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday) || 
      (start.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)) {
      start = start.AddDays(1);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(start.ToString() + " = " + shifts[shift_index].ToString());

    start = start.AddDays(1);

    rotation_count++;
    if (rotation_count > rotation_interval) {
      rotation_count = 1;
      shift_index++;
      if (shift_index >= shifts.Count) {
        shift_index = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Just change the values of the first four varibales as you like.
I tried to make it easy to understand instead of performant or compact.